# ObjectMapper DataTransform.swift failing build xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, objectmapper

I'm starting with iOS development, I'm using swift 2.3. Today I updated my xcode to 8.0 and that was a big problem, because I got some build failures. I tried to solve some of them, but these FBSDK warnings and ObjectMapper errors were persistent problems.

I'm using CocoaPods. This is my podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Lyticx' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Lyticx
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
  pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 3.0'

  pod 'Bolts'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

  target 'LyticxTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'LyticxUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
          end
      end
  end

end
```

And, this is my build log:

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution already? having the same issue